# [Hydro] Error in move_base.launch rviz

Tags: navigation, mapping, rviz, ros-hydro, base-link

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I succed finally to launch my move_base.launch file.
And when with rviz I tried to tell where the robot is in the map, with the 2d Pose Estime, i got this message :

```
Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1407222627.317546291 but the latest data is at time 1407222627.301636934, when looking up transform from frame [map] to frame [base_link])
```

I think that there is a link with my previous problem
http://answers.ros.org/question/187967/groovy-how-to-link-scan-to-base_link/

This is my view_frames
[image: image description]

My local costmap is :

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: /odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

My global costmap is
global_costmap:
global_frame: /map
robot_base_frame: base_link
update_frequency: 5.0
static_map: true

The link beetween map and /odom is done in the move_base.launch file :

```
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_map_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100" />
```

When I launched roswtf i got this error

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
No package or stack in context
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

No errors or warnings
================================================================================
Beginning tests of your ROS graph. These may take awhile...
analyzing graph...
... done analyzing graph
running graph rules...
... done running graph rules
running tf checks, this will take a second...
... tf checks complete

Online checks summary:

Found 3 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /amcl:
   * /tf_static
   * /clock
   * /initialpose
   * /scan
 * /robot_state_publisher:
   * /joint_states
 * /rpid_velocity:
   * /rwheel
 * /diff_tf:
   * /lwheel
   * /rwheel
 * /map_server:
   * /clock
 * /odom_map_broadcaster:
   * /clock
 * /move_base:
   * /move_base_simple/goal
   * /tf_static
   * /clock
 * /lpid_velocity:
   * /lwheel

WARNING These nodes have died:
 * mark2_arduino-2

WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
 * receiving transform from [/robot_state_publisher] that differed from ROS time by 1407396264.96s
 * receiving transform from [/diff_tf] that differed from ROS time by 1407396264.45s


Found 1 error(s).
```

***Update The new tf view_frames***

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188919/%5Bhydro%5D-error-in-move_base.launch-rviz/) by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:\

1. are you by chance using your system clock to set time stamps to any of your transform messages? Your computers system clock isn't same as ros::time since ros time starts from the year 1970. That could be one explanation for the huge time difference it is telling you you are having.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
2) I know you said you are building your own map when I asked if you are using bagged data, but are you sure your not just using recorded wheel odometry and scan data? And building your own map off of replaying that bag file?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-07**:
Whether you are using bag data or not, try setting the use_sim_time parameter to true for your mapping node. This will use the ros simulation time rather then whatever time you are currently using. If that still doesn't work, send me a e-mail and we will figure out things from there.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-09**:
Sorry it doesn't work

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-11**:
email me and i will help you figure this out. krgebis AT gmail DOT com

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-21**:
Setting use_sim_time on a real robot WILL mess things up.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-22**:
No sorry, even without use_sim_time, i have the very same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which frame are you publishing position estimates in? You should make sure that the rviz 2D pose estimate tool is set to publish position estimates in the map frame.

**UPDATE**

The complaint `receiving transform from [/robot_state_publisher] that differed from ROS time by 1407396264.96s` suggests that you have some nodes which are using sim time, and some which are not. You absolutely SHOULD NOT have the /use_sim_time parameter set on a real robot.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
How can I check that pose estimate is publish in the right frame?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
However, when I made a pose estimate, this had been published in the terminal : `[ INFO] [1408552044.916830213]: Setting pose: 0,161 2,930 2,263 [frame=map]`
So I think that I'm publishing in the right frame

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-20**:
The rivz "Tool Properties" panel allows you to configure the 2D pose estimate tool. You should be able to echo the `/initialpose` topic to confirm which frame is being used.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
When I made `rostopic echo /initialpose` i got this

```
header: 
  seq: 3
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: map
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: 0.281967163086
      y: 3.63046169281
      z: 0.0
```

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
orientation:
x: 0.0
y: 0.0
z: 0.912528928351
w: 0.409012169652
covariance: [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06853891945200942]

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
So, is this good?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-20**:
That looks good. Are you sure that the message you're receiving is actually causing problems? Do you know which node it's coming from?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
When I made pose estimate i got this

```
[ WARN] : Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1408553779.104397674 but the latest data is at time 1408553779.067091941, when looking up transform from frame [map] to frame [base_link])
```

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
And my robot is not seen in rviz, not in is real place. Rviz says that the robot is out of the map. The map is a real one.
And then, I can not send the robot somewhere, with 2D Nav Goal, in rviz,
However, I don't know where the issues really come from

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-22**:
Sorry even without use_set_time, I have the very same error

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-22**:
The message is

```
   [ WARN] [1408693106.228430308]: Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1408693106.228264741 but the latest data is at time 1408693106.204777002, when looking up transform from frame [map] to frame [base_link])
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-22**:
That is NOT the same error mentioned in your question - note that the time difference is now < 1 second, where before it was > 1400000000 seconds.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-22**:
You may want to check that the clocks are synchronized between your control PC and your robot.

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-25**:
How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is your local and global costmap parameters set to?

Also can you post a snippet of your code for where you publish the Odom-> map transform, as well as the baselink -> Odom transform?

It will help me better diagnose your problem.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-05**:
Are you using bagged data? (rosbag play)?

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-05**:
No I build my own map.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-06**:
Have you tried decreasing your rate at which the transform happens between then children of base_link and base_link itself? instead of 50 hz, turn them all to 10 as well so that your que doesnt get filled up. Try that and let me know

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-08-06**:
also after everything is running, run "roswtf" in your terminal and let me know if there is any errors

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how you transform from Odom to map within your mapping node, but that is definitely where your error is occurring. Here is a similar post: http://answers.ros.org/question/164911/move_base-and-extrapolation-errors-into-the-future/

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-06**:
But he is trying to change a file named goal_functions.cpp and I don't have it, so what to do?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the issue is broadcast frequency of odom. Publishing it with 50Hz will probably work.

---

Originally posted by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) with karma: 231 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
It doesn't work, i still have the same error, even if i changed the publishing rate
I posted my updated tf view_frames